# Loading multiple CSVs to an object in R

Tags: r, csv, merge, data-analysis

I am attempting to take a bunch of CSV files in a folder (some in subdirectories) and load them all to an object (same columns in each CSV). I have had some luck with rbind, but unable to automate it entirely.

So, the below code seemed to be close, but I get an error.

```
 mytemp <- list.files(path="/PATH-TO-DIR/", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern="*.csv")
    int_list = list
    for (i in mytemp.)
    {
      List1 <- read.csv(mytemp[i])[1:6]
      int_list <- rbind(int_list,List1)
    }
    int_list
```

I get the below error:

```
> int_list = list
> for (i in mytemp)
+ {
+ i
+ List1 <- read.csv(mytemp[i])[1:6]
+ int_list <- rbind(int_list,List1)
+ }
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory
>
```

What am I doing wrong (multiple things, I am guessing :) )?

I am new to R. Most of my experience is with Java, hence the obsession with loops :). I am open to non-loop solutions too.

Thanks!

-S

Comment: First, try doing nothing except printing out `mytemp[i]` in the loop to see if it is what you expect it to be. Then do `List1=read.csv(mytemp[i])` and nothing else and see if that is the problem. If you think you have multiple things wrong, eliminate as much as possible. R, unlike Java, lets you work rapidly and interactively to help debug.

Comment: Try set your path first: setwd("/PATH-TO-DIR/")
And do it from there, because now you are probably not in the right folder.

Comment: You can do this in a one-liner using various functional programming tricks but best to get something that works using paradigms you are familiar with (loops, appending to lists etc) before you venture into stuff like `do.call(rbind,lapply(files, read.csv))` (just for example, that probably wont work for you as-is)

Comment: @Spacedman I am able to print all filenames. i.e. mytemp's contents are perfect (I able to print all the file names). 
You are right about eliminating as much as possible. At this point, I think the problem is with the rbind (especially cos it appends and happens many times.. there are ~500 files), that's where it breaks when I debug

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

#### Edit: added error-catcher for read.csv

```
 mytemp <- list.files(
    path="/PATH-TO-DIR/", 
    recursive = TRUE, 
    full.names = TRUE, 
    pattern="*.csv")
# check here if you're getting NA values somehow, which
# might cause that earlier error.
which(is.na(mytemp))
# if you get any answer other than integer(0), do this:
mytemp <- na.omit(mytemp)

myread <- function(fname, ...) {
    foo <- try(read.csv(fname, ...)[1:6])
    if(class(foo) == "try-error"){
        print(paste("problem reading:", fname))
    } else {
        return(foo)
    }
}

df_list <- lapply(mytemp, myread)
big_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: Not sure what the above does, but here's the error message I get.

Comment: Not sure what the above does, but here's the error message I get.

> mytemp <- list.files(
+ path="/Users/sanand/Documents/Yuktix/Data-Sandesh",
+ recursive = TRUE,
+ full.names = TRUE,
+ pattern="*.csv")
> which(is.na(mytemp))
integer(0)
> mytemp <- na.omit(mytemp)
> df_list <- lapply(mytemp,read.csv)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
> big_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
Error in do.call(rbind, df_list) : object 'df_list' not found
>

Comment: Sorry for the spam above
Not sure what this does, but here's the error message I get: 
**> mytemp <- list.files(
+ path="/Users/sanand/Documents/Yuktix/Data-Sandesh",
+ recursive = TRUE,
+ full.names = TRUE,
+ pattern="*.csv")
> which(is.na(mytemp))
integer(0)
> mytemp <- na.omit(mytemp)
> df_list <- lapply(mytemp,read.csv)
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
> big_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
Error in do.call(rbind, df_list) : object 'df_list' not found
> **

Comment: OK, I am giving up on formatting on comments for now. Sorry!

Comment: Aha. Thanks. The `integer(0)` bit tells me that there's no problem with the file names. Sounds like it's blowing up due formatting (or blank-ness) in the content one of your files. I'll edit the above to find which file.